# Avoid Video compression while picking video using uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using UIImagePickerController to allow my user to select a video .

When the user selects the "Choose" button on the second screen, the view displays a progress bar and a "Compressing Video..." message.

Is there some way I can avoid this compression operation?

Comment: are there any solutions found of your question?

Comment: @pop924: can you provide more explanation of your problem..??

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the `videoQuality` property of `UIImagePickerController`

The video quality setting specified by this property is used during video recording. **It is also used whenever picking a recorded movie. Specifically, if the video quality setting is lower than the video quality of an existing movie, displaying that movie in the picker results in transcoding the movie to the lower quality.** [UIImagePickerController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/videoQuality)

Available quality values are:

`UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh`
`UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium`
`UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow`
`UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480`
`UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720`
`UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540`

Please see [UIImagePickerController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImagePickerControllerQualityType) for detail.

Comment: This doesn't work. Maybe try using a library like ELC to choose videos. This doesn't do compression and passes back asset URLs you can use to get the videos.